# Mysqli->ssl_set php accepting any string

Tags: php, ssl, mysqli

Hi I have possibly the oddest thing ever, or maybe its the heat today.

I am trying to connect to a mysql instance with a user that was setup with "REQUIRE SSL"

The user works fine and using mysql from the linux command line everything works as expected.

Now when I use the code bellow, with the correct real_connect() params php connects to mysql 
even though I have passed junk into ssl_set()

```
$mysqli->ssl_set('asdad', null, null, null, null);
```

If I set ssl_set like so, or comment the line out

```
$mysqli->ssl_set('', null, null, null, null);
```

I get an ssl error as expected.

Any ideas on why it is allowing the ssl connection with a random string for the key? The docs say this is a file location?

```
$mysqli = mysqli_init();

$mysqli->ssl_set('asdad', null, null, null, null);

$connected = $mysqli->real_connect('HOST',
                                   'USER',
                                   'PASSWROD',
                                   'DATABASE',
                                   3306,
                                   null,
                                   MYSQLI_CLIENT_SSL);
```

**EDIT 1:**

I have tested this on 3 sperete machines and get the same probelm. I have tested on php5.3, php5.4 and php5.5

**EDIT 2:**

If I remove ssl_set completely and only set MYSQLI_CLIENT_SSL it still connects. Looks like there is a default cert OR it is not validating anthing.

**UPDATE 1:**

So I thought that it was because this is an RDS instance and AWS say this

```
These certificates are signed by a certificate authority.
```

and therefore there was no need to set custom certs in php. However to prove this point I went back to the command line and tied

```
mysql -uUSER -pPASSWORD -hHOST --ssl
```

instead of

```
mysql -uUSER -pPASSWORD -hHOST --ssl_ca=mysql-ssl-ca-cert.pem
```

The first command does not work the second does work. Still very confused about what is going on here.

Comment: I don't know that this is duplicate, but could be useful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14053160/php-ignores-ssl-certificates-when-connecting-to-mysql

Comment: Thanks but I saw that post before. If I am reading it correctly they could not connect at all. I can connect with an invalid/none existant ssl cert. Which I should not be able to do. I am woundering if there is a default cert in php somehwere and it is connecting over ssl but not validating the connection. Is this possible?

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I'm having the same exact issue right now and I can't figure it out for the life of me!